# Unable to find ManagedAttributes in jetty jars

Tags: jetty, cometd

Which jar correspond to this `org.eclipse.jetty.server.context.ManagedAttributes`?

I am trying to expose bayeux mbeans as documented [here](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/). But just out of curiosity I was trying to look for source of above mentioned file and am unable to find it.

All search results are ending in annotation jar which is a different class.

P.S. Jetty 9.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **string** `org.eclipse.jetty.server.context.ManagedAttributes` is a constant field of class [`ContextHandler`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.java).

`ContextHandler` will look up the beans and update the beans belonging to this context.

The `jetty-jmx` module registers itself as a listener for bean updates, and when an update event is fired, it wraps the correspondent bean in a `MBean`, and export it to the `MBeanServer`.